# How can I get the metadata of a couchbase object in node?

Tags: node.js, metadata, couchbase

I use a TTL of one month on my users in couchbase and use "touch" to update this TTL every time I see one again within this month.

I need to check the TTL of users to do special actions if they get to old for example.

I cannot use an "updated_at" field in the object since it will not be updated via the touch method, and I prefer using the touch to minimise interaction between services for performance issues.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not yet possible.

Answered from the couchbase forum : https://forums.couchbase.com/t/how-can-i-get-the-metadata-of-a-couchbase-object-in-node/13630 :

> Unfortunately it is not currently possible to reliably fetch the
>   current TTL of an item. The upcoming Couchbase Server release should
>   be able to fetch this information using a new virtual attribute fetch,
>   but this was not yet available in currently released versions. In the
>   meantime, we do suggest performing a subdocument upsert to update a
>   field within the document with an updated timestamp.